# Define a no-op color name which is always the current color

Tags: color

Using `xcolor` I like to define a named color which actually does **not** change the current color. So `\textcolor{mycolor}{text}` should print `text` in the currently active color. In other words: I'm looking for a way to define a no-op color.

I'm not talking about the special color name '`.`', which refers to the currently used color. Using `\colorlet{mycolor}{.}` will simply define `mycolor` to the color used at that moment. However, having a names *alias* of '`.`' would do the trick.

About the background:
In my `ydoc` bundle which I used for the package manuals of mine I use predefined styles for certain repeatable used items. For example package names are formatted using `\pkg{name}` which uses `\pkgstyle` internally to format the name. This style macro uses, beside other things, the color `pkg` to color the package names. By default I do not want to have the package names colored in a different way, so the `pkg` is defined to be black. This is fine for normal, black text, but if `\pkg` is used inside a colored text the package names are still black. Some goes for all other macros like this which all use this generic set of macros.

My question is now if it is possible to define a named color with `xcolor` which actually does not change the current color. This would allow to disable the use of a special color without redefining the style macro to not include `\textcolor`. It would be nice if this special no-op color could be copied using `\colorlet` to other color names as well.

A MWE would be the following. The word 'test' should always have the same color as 'before' and 'after'. The definition of `\myformat` should not be changed, only the definition of `mycolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{mycolor}{.}% Wanted: Always be the currently active color
\newcommand{\myformat}[1]{\textcolor{mycolor}{\ttfamily #1}}
\begin{document}

before \myformat{test} after

\color{blue}
before \myformat{test} after

\color{red}
before \myformat{test} after

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why special color '`.`' cannot be used?

Comment: Although this does not answer the general question, in this specific case one could redefine `\textcolor` to gobble its colour argument `#1` and only typeset the text part `#2`. *And*, this redefinition could be done within `\myformat` to localize it.

Comment: And I'm sure you know that you can use `\colorlet{mycolor}{.}` in the definition of `\myformat`. So I still cannot understand your purpose. Is there any special reason make `ydoc` prevent using such techniques?

Comment: @LeoLiu: I want that by default no color is used, i.e. the current color is not changed, but the user should be able to redefine the `pkg` color to a specific color. So basically, if no color is defined I don't want a `\textcolor` to be used (or at least it should not do anything), but if a color it defined it should be used. `\colorlet{mycolor}{.}` would simply define `mycolor` to be the current color, like black, but if the color changes `.` would then be the new color, but `mycolor` would still be black.

Comment: @Werner: I don't want to redefine the formatting macro, but rather able to disable the color change by redefining the named color.

Comment: What a user can do? Is he able to redefine `\myformat`? Or he can only redefine `mycolor` by `\colorlet`, `\definecolor` etc.? For the former case, you don't need this function; for the latter case, you can test whether `mycolor` is a predefined.

Comment: @LeoLiu: The user can redefine both `\myformat` and `mycolor`, but should not require to redefine the macro depending if a color is wanted or not. I could of course keep the color undefined and test if the color is defined, but I'm looking for a different approach ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I think you know this:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Users cannot touch these
% But users can change pkgcolor
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\pkg[1]{%
  \textcolor{\ifcsname\string\color@pkgcolor\endcsname pkgcolor\else .\fi}{#1}}

\begin{document}

The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.

{\color{red}
The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.}


\colorlet{pkgcolor}{blue}

The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.

{\color{red}
The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.}
\end{document}
```

Thanks egerg for `\csname\string\color@xyz\endcsname`.

---

But I prefer a key-value interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Users cannot touch these
% But users can use \ydocset to change pkgcolor key
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{ydoc}{pkgcolor}{%
  \def\pkg@color{#1}}
\newcommand\ydocset[1]{\setkeys{ydoc}{#1}}
\ydocset{pkgcolor=.}
\newcommand\pkg[1]{%
  \textcolor{\pkg@color}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.

{\color{red}
The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.}


\ydocset{pkgcolor=blue}

The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.

{\color{red}
The package \pkg{ydoc} is good.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

When one says `\definecolor{xyz}{...}{...}`, **xcolor** defines the macro

```
\\color@xyz
```

that is, more precisely,

```
\csname\string\color@xyz\endcsname
```

In particular `\csname\string\color@.\endcsname` is a macro expanding to the current color; so

```
\expandafter\let\csname\string\color@mycolor\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname\string\color@.\endcsname
```

would seem a way to go. However, as you observe, this is like `\colorlet{mycolor}{.}`.

A way out seems to be to add the definition of the requested pseudocolor to `\XC@display`:

```
\makeatletter
\preto\XC@display{\XC@bcolor\XC@let@cN{\string\color@mycolor}\XC@current@color}
\makeatother
\colorlet{mycolor}{.} % initialization
```

Not very satisfying, I guess.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It basically is the same as `\colorlet{mycolor}{.}`, i.e. it just copies the current color. The problem is that `.` is redefined every time the color is changed. I also tried `\expandafter\def\csname\string\color@mycolor\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\csname\string\color@.\endcsname}` to always use the current definition of `.`, but this causes warnings by `xcolor` that the color definition is incompatible, because it expands the macro once to check its definition.

Comment: It works. Anyway I feel painful to hack into `xcolor.sty`. And it may be unsafe.

Comment: @LeoLiu I'm not satisfied, too. Probably the best way is to make a feature request.