# advanced string highlighting in listings

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I'm using `listings` to display ruby code with highlighting. I have the following test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{Ruby} {
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
    numberstyle={\tiny},
    numbers=left,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2, 
    sensitive = true
}

\lstset{language=Ruby}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Ruby,float=ht,caption={...},label={lst:sourcecode},captionpos=b]
def some_function
  File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
    [...]
    # a comment
    f.puts "whatever #{some_variable} another string part"
    f.puts 'this string contains apostrophes: \'random word\''
    [...]
  end
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: example output]

Of course, `#{some_variable}` is highlighted in purple/mauve because I set it as the stringstyle, but that's not really correct, since the syntax `#{}` will execute the content instead of interpreting this block as string (only if inside `" "`, not with `' '`, but I'd be willing to ignore this subtlety).

My question is, is there a way to configure the highlighting to correctly represent this, so that `#{some_variable}` has the default color?

EDIT: with the answer presented by SDF, it now looks like this:

[image: slightly wrong solution]

If you compare the two pictures, you'll see that now the escaped apostrophes around `random word` aren't getting ignored like before (which was the correct behavior).

EDIT 2: while i was able to solve this problem by omitting `string=[d]{'},`, I noticed two more problems. The example now looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.25}

\lstdefinestyle{Ruby} {
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
    numberstyle={\tiny},
    numbers=left,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2, 
    sensitive = true,
    morestring=*[d]{"},
    morestring=[s][]{\#\{}{\}},
    procnamekeys={def},
    procnamestyle=\color{red},
}

\lstset{language=Ruby}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Ruby,float=ht,caption={...},label={lst:sourcecode},captionpos=b]
def some_function
  File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
    [...]
    # a comment
    f.puts "whatever #{some_variable} another string part"
    f.puts 'this string contains apostrophes: \'random word\''
    f.puts 'i do love keywords like class'
    f.puts "i do love keywords like class"
    f.puts "now single quotes 'inside #{double quotes}'"
    [...]
  end
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: worng keyword highlights and nested quote problem]

Keywords inside double quotes are now getting highlighted, and also single quotes inside double quotes cause the original problem to resurface.

This is slowly geting out of hand... Maybe I should really switch to minted.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @dexteritas done (:

Comment: Could you update your MWE so it reflects the problem you now have?

Comment: @Daniel sure, there you go

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the `*` option makes `morestring` not only look for further delimiters, but also for keywords inside the content. My idea was to compensate for that by temporarily resetting `keywords` or `keywordstyle`, but that did not work out: `morestring=*[d][\color{red}\lstset{keywords={}}]{"}`

Comment: also, even looking for further delimiters except the `#{}` one is problematic, see the last sample with the nested quotes...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note:**
I updated the whole answer to take the two edits into account.
There are a lot of little hacks, but I'm afraid the more precise we want to be using `listings`, the more hacks we'll need to add.
See at the end of the answer for an alternative solution using `minted`.

## Solving the initial issue using [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings)

You can allow `listings` to detect delimiters inside another delimiter by adding a `*` in its definition:

```
morestring=*[d]{"}
```

Then we define `#{` and `}` as special delimiters. We give them their own style by adding a second pair of square brackets:

```
morestring=[s][]{\#\{}{\}}
```

Here, we add empty brackets, which means the default style will be used.
Also, don't forget to escape special characters such as `#`, `{`, etc.
For more detailed explanations, have a look at `listings` documentation, section 3.3.

**Remark:**
`s` option means that the beginning and ending delimiters are different, `d` that they are the same.
One has to use `b` instead of `d` to enable backslash escaping. I made that mistake in my original answer.
It's also worth noting that Ruby, like most languages, already has a basic definition, which includes most strings, so there's no need to re-define it all
(unless we want to override it, and we will).

This is the `\lstset` that produces the output as seen in the OP's first edit:

```
\lstdefinestyle{Ruby} {
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
    numberstyle={\tiny},
    numbers=left,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2, 
    morestring=[d]{'}, % wrong: should be [b]
    morestring=*[d]{"},
    morestring=[s][]{\#\{}{\}},
}
```

## Solving additional issues

### Keywords inside strings are getting highlighted

As Daniel said in a comment, the star in `morestring=*[d]{"}` causes it to look further for more strings *and* keywords.
That's what we want regarding "`#{`-`}` strings", but it also happens for keywords.
`listings` doesn't allow to specify what exactly we'll be looking for inside the strings, so we'll have find another work-around.

Now, `listings` offers a `**` option so that the styles of the string and its special content can be cumulated.
For example, when we do this:

```
morestring=**[d][\color{mauve}]{"},
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
```

`listings` will make keywords inside double-quotes both bold *and* mauve. Thing is, we need to "cumulate" colors.

```
morestring=**[d][\color{mauve}]{"},
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
```

In this case, keywords inside strings are processed with `\color{mauve} \color{blue}`, and that's bad: the keyword style overrides the string style.
My hack was to replace the keyword style with a new command that checks the current color and sets it to blue if it's not already mauve:

```
\def\bluecolorifnotalreadymauve{%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\currentcolor
    \extractcolorspec{mauve}\stringcolor
    \ifx\currentcolor\stringcolor\else
        \color{blue}%
    \fi
}
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245417) for the solution.)

Now we also lose our original `#{}` fix, because its (empty) style is "cumulated" with the `\color{mauve}` from `""`.
Let's cumulate it back:

```
morestring=[s][\color{black}]{\#\{}{\}},
```

### Single quotes cause the `#{}` problem to resurface

Just like keywords, single-quotes strings are re-processed inside double-quotes strings.
And `listings` hasn't been told to look inside single-quotes strings, so we'll have to change them the same way:

```
morestring=**[d]{'},
```

And now we lose backslash escaping.
For an unknown reason, `b` option doesn't work well with `**`.
Well, while we're at it…

```
morestring=[d]{\\'},
```

### Full updated MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.25}

\def\bluecolorifnotalreadymauve{%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\currentcolor
    \extractcolorspec{mauve}\stringcolor
    \ifx\currentcolor\stringcolor\else
        \color{blue}%
    \fi
}

\lstdefinestyle{Ruby} {
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbers=left,
    keywordstyle=\bluecolorifnotalreadymauve,
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2,
    moredelim=[s][\color{black}]{\#\{}{\}}, % same as morestring in this case
    morestring=**[d]{'},
    morestring=[d]{\\'},
    morestring=**[d]{"},
    procnamekeys={def}, % bonus, for function names
    procnamestyle=\color{red},
}

\lstset{language=Ruby}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Ruby,float=ht,caption={...},label={lst:sourcecode},captionpos=b]
def some_function
  File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
    [...]
    # a comment
    f.puts "whatever #{some_variable} another string part"
    f.puts 'this string contains apostrophes: \'random word\''
    f.puts 'i do love keywords like class'
    f.puts "i do love keywords like class"
    f.puts "now single quotes 'inside #{double quotes}'"
    [...]
  end
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: updated Ruby code with listings]

## Alternate approach: using [`minted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted)

`minted` already does everything you want, and so much more! Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
  \begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize, linenos]{Ruby}
  def some_function
    File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
      [...]
      # a comment
      f.puts "whatever #{some_variable} another string part"
      f.puts 'this string contains apostrophes: \'random word\''
      f.puts 'i do love keywords like class'
      f.puts "i do love keywords like class"
      f.puts "now single quotes 'inside #{double quotes}'"
      [...]
    end
  end
  \end{minted}
  \caption{...}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

This is the output with the default style:

[image: updated Ruby code with minted]

The main downside of `minted` is that it relies on [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to do the processing, which means:

1. It can be a bit tricky to install.
2. It's harder to customize. (But once we know how to, it can be very powerful.)

Comment: thanks for the extensive answer! i'll try the solution for listings as soon as i can, looking good so far

Comment: it's working for the example I have in my question, but it breaks the behavior for escaped string delimiters (`\'`) - I'll edit the question and add a line with an example

Comment: oh well, already found the solution: I removed the `string=[d]{'}` line and now it works as intended - would you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: found even more problems, I added examples to the question... maybe i really should switch to minted

Comment: @TheFlow0360 I'm currently at work, I'll try and see what I can do in a few hours. Since you removed `string=[d]{'}`, where do you parse strings between single quotes? Replacing the option from `d` to `b` should allow backslash escaping.

Comment: it's the default parsing when selecting `Ruby` as language, I guess

Comment: "just a quick update" - that seems like it was a lot of work! Thank you, that's working fine! I already looked into minted, the highlighting works fine, but I had some trouble when customizing everything else - I guess I'll go back to listings for now