# How do I customize Circuit_macros in listings?

Tags: macros, color, listings, languages

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{Others}{RGB}{0,110,40}      % Green
\definecolor{Character}{RGB}{146,76,157} % Purple
\definecolor{Number}{RGB}{176,128,0}     % Brown

\lstdefinestyle{circuit_macros}
{
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\null,
literate=*{0}{{\textcolor{Number}{0}}}{1}%
      {1}{{\textcolor{Number}{1}}}{1}%
       {2}{{\textcolor{Number}{2}}}{1}%
       {3}{{\textcolor{Number}{3}}}{1}%
       {4}{{\textcolor{Number}{4}}}{1}%
       {5}{{\textcolor{Number}{5}}}{1}%
       {6}{{\textcolor{Number}{6}}}{1}%
       {7}{{\textcolor{Number}{7}}}{1}%
       {8}{{\textcolor{Number}{8}}}{1}%
       {9}{{\textcolor{Number}{9}}}{1}%
       {.0}{{\textcolor{Number}{.0}}}{1}%
       {.1}{{\color{Number}{.1}}}{1}%
       {.2}{{\color{Number}{.2}}}{1}%
       {.3}{{\color{Number}{.3}}}{1}%
       {.4}{{\color{Number}{.4}}}{1}%
       {.5}{{\color{Number}{.5}}}{1}%
       {.6}{{\color{Number}{.6}}}{1}%
       {.7}{{\color{Number}{.7}}}{1}%
       {.8}{{\color{Number}{.8}}}{1}%
       {.9}{{\color{Number}{.9}}}{1}%
       {(}{{\color{Character}{(}}}{1}%
       {)}{{\color{Character}{)}}}{1}%
       {/}{{\color{black}{/}}}{1}% 
       {:}{{\color{Character}{:}}}{1}%
       {;}{{\color{black}{;}}}{1}%
       {,}{{\color{black}{,}}}{1}%
       {.}{{\color{black}{.}}}{1}%
       {(}{{\color{Character}{(}}}{1}%
       {)}{{\color{Character}{)}}}{1}%
       ,
morekeywords={In1,In2,In3},
keywordstyle=\color{black},
morekeywords=[2]{scale,above,with,at,Here,line,to,end,start,from,ljust},
keywordstyle=[2]{\bf\color{black}},
morekeywords=[3]{PS,PE},
keywordstyle=[3]{\color{Character}},
morekeywords=[4]{corner,Out,In1,In2,In3,In4},
keywordstyle=[4]{\color{black}},
morekeywords=[5]{down_,up_,elen_,right_,log_init,NOT_gate,dot,AND_gate,OR_gate},
keywordstyle=[5]\color{Others},
sensitive=false,
comment=[l][\color{gray}]{\#},
string=[b]",
stringstyle=\color{red},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=circuit_macros]
% `logic.cir'

.PS

scale=25.4
log_init

#setrgb(0,0,1) # Blue Color
#dot(,,1)

O:(0,0)

"A" at Here above;DA:dot(,,1);
line down_ elen_/2 with .start at DA.s;dot;{A:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LA:line down_ to (Here.x,A.end.y);

"B" at (elen_,0) above;DB:dot(,,1);
line down_ elen_/2 with .start at DB.s;dot;{B:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LB:line to (Here.x,B.end.y);

"C" at (2*elen_,0) above;DC:dot(,,1);
line down_ elen_/2 with .start at DC.s;dot;{C:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LC:line to (Here.x,C.end.y);

right_

X1:AND_gate(2) at (3*elen_,LC.y+15)
line from X1.In1 to (LA.x,X1.In1.y);dot
line from X1.In2 to (LB.x,X1.In2.y);dot

X2:AND_gate(2) at (X1.x,X1.y-15);
line from X2.In1 to (LB.x,X2.In1.y);dot
line from X2.In2 to (C.x,X2.In2.y);dot

X3:AND_gate(3) at (X1.x,X1.y-30);
line from X3.In1 to (A.x,X3.In1.y);dot
line from X3.In2 to (B.x,X3.In2.y);dot
line from X3.In3 to (LC.x,X3.In3.y);dot

line right_ elen_ from X2.Out;X4:OR_gate(3) with .In2 at Here;
line right_ elen_/2 from X1.Out;corner;line down_ to (Here.x,X4.In1.y);corner;line to X4.In1
line right_ elen_/2 from X3.Out;corner;line up_ to (Here.x,X4.In3.y);corner;line to X4.In3

line right_ elen_/2 from X4.Out; "X" ljust;dot(,,1);

.PE
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

And output (Of course there are errors. This was what I could do.)

[image]

But original output

[image]

What I want to do;

1. codes with digits such as `In1`, `In2` should be black.
2. at the end of the `:` or characters starting `;` and ending `:` must be purple. Such as `;DA:`, `X1:` written in source code. Other `DA`, `X1` should be black.
3. When I copy and paste the output into the notebook, there is a space between characters. So when I paste it into its own program it gives an error.

[image]

Are these possible?

Related to: [advanced string highlighting in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378307/advanced-string-highlighting-in-listings/378367)

Comment: Your questions seem to be responded explicitly in your MWE. Precisely, 1) your code is already doing so: `morecomment=[l][\color{gray}]{\#},`. 2) You can do the same case for `)` as you have defined for `"` in `morestring=[b]"`. I don't have a solution for your third question. For 4, what about defining a new array like `morekeywords` and then set a colour for?

Comment: I will check...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{standalone}% for demontration only!
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}% for demontration only!
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{Others}{RGB}{0,110,40}      % Green
\definecolor{Character}{RGB}{146,76,157} % Purple
\definecolor{Number}{RGB}{176,128,0}     % Brown

\lstdefinestyle{circuit_macros}
{
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\null,
literate=*{,}{{\color{black}{,}}}1%
       0{{\textcolor{Number}0}}1%
       1{{\textcolor{Number}1}}1%
       2{{\textcolor{Number}2}}1%
       3{{\textcolor{Number}3}}1%
       4{{\textcolor{Number}4}}1%
       5{{\textcolor{Number}5}}1%
       6{{\textcolor{Number}6}}1%
       7{{\textcolor{Number}7}}1%
       8{{\textcolor{Number}8}}1%
       9{{\textcolor{Number}9}}1%
       ({{\color{Character}{(}}}1%
       ){{\color{Character}{)}}}1%
       /{{\color{black}{/}}}1% 
       :{{\color{Character}{:}}}1%
       ;{{\color{black}{;}}}1%
       .{{\color{black}{.}}}1%
       ({{\color{Character}{(}}}1%
       {.0}{{\textcolor{Number}{.0}}}1%
       {.1}{{\color{Number}{.1}}}1%
       {.2}{{\color{Number}{.2}}}1%
       {.3}{{\color{Number}{.3}}}1%
       {.4}{{\color{Number}{.4}}}1%
       {.5}{{\color{Number}{.5}}}1%
       {.6}{{\color{Number}{.6}}}1%
       {.7}{{\color{Number}{.7}}}1%
       {.8}{{\color{Number}{.8}}}1%
       {.9}{{\color{Number}{.9}}}1%
       %
       *{{\color{black}{*}}}2%
       {O:}{{\color{Character}{O:}}}2%
       {A.}{{\color{black}{A.}}}2%
       {B.}{{\color{black}{B.}}}2%
       {C.}{{\color{black}{C.}}}2%
       {A:}{{\color{Character}{A:}}}2%
       {B:}{{\color{Character}{B:}}}2%
       {C:}{{\color{Character}{C:}}}2%
       {DA:}{{\color{Character}{DA:}}}3%
       {DB:}{{\color{Character}{DB:}}}3%
       {DC:}{{\color{Character}{DC:}}}3%
       {LA.}{{\color{black}{LA.}}}3%
       {LB.}{{\color{black}{LB.}}}3%
       {LC.}{{\color{black}{LC.}}}3%
       {LA:}{{\color{Character}{LA:}}}3%
       {LB:}{{\color{Character}{LB:}}}3%
       {LC:}{{\color{Character}{LC:}}}3%
       {X1}{{\color{black}{X1}}}2%
       {X1:}{{\color{Character}{X1:}}}3%
       {X2}{{\color{black}{X2:}}}2%
       {X2:}{{\color{Character}{X2:}}}3%
       {X3}{{\color{black}{X3:}}}2%
       {X3:}{{\color{Character}{X3:}}}3%
       {X4}{{\color{black}{X4:}}}2%
       {X4:}{{\color{Character}{X4:}}}3%
       {"A"}{{\bf\color{red}{"A"}}}3%
       {"B"}{{\bf\color{red}{"B"}}}3%
       {"C"}{{\bf\color{red}{"C"}}}3%
       {"X"}{{\color{red}{"X"}}}3%
       {In1}{{\color{black}{In1}}}3%
       {In2}{{\color{black}{In2}}}3%
       {In3}{{\color{black}{In3}}}3%
       {In4}{{\color{black}{In4}}}3%
       ,
emph={scale,above,with,at,Here,line,to,end,start,from,ljust},
emphstyle={\bf\color{black}},
morekeywords=[3]{PS,PE},
keywordstyle=[3]{\color{Character}},
morekeywords=[5]{down_,up_,elen_,right_,log_init,NOT_gate,dot,AND_gate,OR_gate},
keywordstyle=[5]\color{Others},
sensitive=false,
morecomment=[l][\color{gray}]{\#},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=circuit_macros]
% `logic.cir'

.PS

scale=25.4
log_init

#setrgb(0,0,1) # Blue Color
#dot(,,1)

O:(0,0)

"A" at Here above;DA:dot(,,1);
line down_ elen_/2 with .start at DA.s;dot;{A:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LA:line down_ to (Here.x,A.end.y);

"B" at (elen_,0) above;DB:dot(,,1);
line down_ elen_/2 with .start at DB.s;dot;{B:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LB:line to (Here.x,B.end.y);

"C" at (2*elen_,0) above;DC:dot(,,1);
line down_ elen_/2 with .start at DC.s;dot;{C:line down_ 3.5*elen_};line right_ elen_/2;corner;
line down_ elen_/2;NOT_gate;LC:line to (Here.x,C.end.y);

right_

X1:AND_gate(2) at (3*elen_,LC.y+15)
line from X1.In1 to (LA.x,X1.In1.y);dot
line from X1.In2 to (LB.x,X1.In2.y);dot

X2:AND_gate(2) at (X1.x,X1.y-15);
line from X2.In1 to (LB.x,X2.In1.y);dot
line from X2.In2 to (C.x,X2.In2.y);dot

X3:AND_gate(3) at (X1.x,X1.y-30);
line from X3.In1 to (A.x,X3.In1.y);dot
line from X3.In2 to (B.x,X3.In2.y);dot
line from X3.In3 to (LC.x,X3.In3.y);dot

line right_ elen_ from X2.Out;X4:OR_gate(3) with .In2 at Here;
line right_ elen_/2 from X1.Out;corner;line down_ to (Here.x,X4.In1.y);corner;line to X4.In1
line right_ elen_/2 from X3.Out;corner;line up_ to (Here.x,X4.In3.y);corner;line to X4.In3

line right_ elen_/2 from X4.Out; "X" ljust;dot(,,1);

.PE
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```