# Indicating single quotes as delimiters in Listings

Tags: listings, packages

I'm using the Listings package and am having a bit of trouble properly highlighting a string such as

```
string x = 'a'
```

with single quotes. The issue is that in Latex the left single quote operator (`) and right single quote operator (') are not the same. I added the following modifiers to my \lstset to try and fix this:

```
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  morestring=[d]{`},
```

(where mauve is `\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}`)

but this simply gives me output like the following (note how the semicolon is still mauve and thus the delimiters aren't working correctly):

[image]

So I can't figure out how to indicate that ' and ` should both be delimiters. Alternatively, perhaps there is just some symmetric (i.e. not left or right) single quote I can use in Latex?

Thanks so much

Comment: I am a bit confused with your question. Are you actually typing `char c = \`f'` inside your listing? If so, why?

Comment: In any case, according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378367/119 if you use `morestring=[d]{\`}` this means that you are declaring strings to be contained between a pair of backticks (`[d]` requires the two delimiters to be the same). If you want to have a pair of unequal delimiters, you need to use `[s]` instead. Probably `[s][]{\`}{'}` would work, but I don't use the package.

Comment: aha thanks for this `morestring=[s]{\`}{'}` ended up working!