# Test if Current Color is Black

Tags: color

The MWE below does exactly what I want via the `\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack` macro:

[image]

`\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack` is intended to change the color of its parameter to blue, *only* if the current color *is* black.  Otherwise, the current color is to be used.

### Questions:

- I expected that `xcolor` would provide a macro to do this, but was not able to locate it.  Thus, wondering if there any obvious problems with this approach, or is there an official interface that is provided.

### References:

- This solution is adapted from [How to get a textual representation of the current color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384903/4301)
  .

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

%% At this point the default color is black so save that.
\edef\BlackColor{\csname\string\color@.\endcsname}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@CurrentColor}{}% Make sure we are not using an existing macro
\newcommand*{\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack}[1]{%
    \edef\@CurrentColor{\csname\string\color@.\endcsname}% Get current color
    \IfStrEq{\@CurrentColor}{\BlackColor}{%
        {\bfseries\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}% current color IS black
    }{%
        {\bfseries\ttfamily#1}%  current color is NOT black
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Following should be in blue:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{blue}.

\color{red}
    Following should be in red:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{red}.

\color{blue}
    Following should also be in blue:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{blue}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `color` stores the current colour in `\current@color`. So you could do `\usepackage{xcolor}{\color{black}\global\let\my@black@color\current@color}\newcommand*\ifblack{\ifx\my@black@color\current@color}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Better yet: `\sbox0{\color{black}\global\let\my@black@color\current@color}` so no whatsit is added to the main vertical list.

Comment: I wonder why Peter Grill's definition of `\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack` does not work with line breaks; for me, it results in a `Runaway argument?`.

Comment: @Anna: I suspect one of your packages is out of date, or perhaps you have older auxillary files lying around. If deleting the auxillary files and then running does not resolve the issue, I suggest you post a question and use `\listfiles` to output the version information and include that in your question.

Comment: @PeterGrill I cleared the cache and used overleaf, so I doubt its either of them. I have made a new post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/644598/241569)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interface? Use `expl3`, of course!

With `\storecolor` you can store the representation of the colors you need to do comparison with.

I define a generic comparison command and also yours as a special case.

At begin document each color in the list passed to `\storecolors` and also `black` are converted in the internal representation and stored in a property list. This is for greater efficiency and not actually necessary: it saves several steps in the evaluation.

The main command converts the current color in the internal representation and compares it with the color given as the first argument (only named colors, but this could be generalized). If the test returns true, the color specified as second argument is used to print the third argument; otherwise no color change is performed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\perhapschangecolor}{mmm}
 {% #1 = color to compare with current
  % #2 = color to use if match
  % #3 = text
  \peter_color_change:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
% the same but with black and blue preset
\NewDocumentCommand{\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack}{m}
 {
  \perhapschangecolor{black}{blue}{#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\storecolors}{m}
 {% black is always stored
  \AtBeginDocument { \peter_color_store:n { black,#1 } }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_peter_color_stored_prop
\tl_new:N \l__peter_color_current_tl

\cs_new:Nn \peter_color_store:n
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
   {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
      \color{##1}
      \driver_color_pickup:N \l_tmpa_tl
      \prop_gput:NnV \g_peter_color_stored_prop { ##1 } \l_tmpa_tl
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \peter_color_change:nnn
 {
  \driver_color_pickup:N \l__peter_color_current_tl
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_peter_color_stored_prop { #1 }
   {% more efficient test
    \str_if_eq:eeTF
     { \l__peter_color_current_tl }
     { \prop_item:Nn \g_peter_color_stored_prop { #1 } }
     { \textcolor{#2}{#3} }
     { #3 }
   }
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box
     {
      \color{#1}
      \driver_color_pickup:N \l_tmpa_tl
      \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
     }
    \driver_color_pickup:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \g_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpa_tl }
     { \textcolor{#2}{#3} }
     { #3 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\storecolors{red!60}

\begin{document}

    Following should be in blue:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{blue}

\color{red}
    Following should be in red:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{red}

\color{blue}
    Following should be in blue:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{blue}

\color{black}
    Following should be in pale red:
    \perhapschangecolor{black}{red!60}{red!60}

\color{red!60}
    Following should be in pale red:
    \perhapschangecolor{black}{red!60}{red!60} 

\color{blue}
    Following should be in blue:
    \perhapschangecolor{black}{red!60}{blue}

    % blue has not been stored, but the test succeeds as well
    Following should be in pale red:
    \perhapschangecolor{blue}{red!60}{red!60}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In `\clist_map_inline:nn` in `\peter_color_store:n` you're missing an additional group around `\color{##1}`.

Comment: @Skillmon It's not necessary, as the code is executed inside a box being built and then unused.

Comment: I'd still do so, just to not lead to bad practise. Somebody not knowing the limitations and seeing this code might write faulty code because he thinks it's generally safe to use it inside a box.