# Test if Current Color is Black (with line breaks)

Tags: color, line-breaking

This is a question that arose from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466026/241569), where the original poster defined the macro `\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack`; it changes the color of text to blue only if the current color is black.

I have used the code provided in that original post, and then added a single line break when using the new macro; below is the code.

### **Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles %% first thing Anna added
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

%% At this point the default color is black so save that.
\edef\BlackColor{\csname\string\color@.\endcsname}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@CurrentColor}{}% Make sure we are not using an existing macro
\newcommand*{\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack}[1]{%
    \edef\@CurrentColor{\csname\string\color@.\endcsname}% Get current color
    \IfStrEq{\@CurrentColor}{\BlackColor}{%
        {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}% current color IS black
    }{%
        {#1}%  current color is NOT black
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


    Following is blue:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{blue}.

\color{red}
    Following is red:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{red}.

\color{blue}
    Following is blue:
    \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack{blue
    
    
    with a linebreak}. %%%% Second and last thing Anna added
\end{document}
```

### **Question:**

Why am I getting the following error?

```
Runaway argument?
{blue 
! Paragraph ended before \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.34 
     
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

I have done this on overleaf, with all aux files cleared beforehand.

### **Log file:**

For completeness, here is the log.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)  17 MAY 2022 22:07
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**name.tex
(/compile/name.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\c@figure=\count174
\c@table=\count175
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count176
\decimalpart=\count177
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count178
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
) (/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count179
\scratchdimen=\dimen135
\scratchbox=\box46
\nofMPsegments=\count180
\nofMParguments=\count181
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count182
\MPscratchDim=\dimen136
\MPnumerator=\count183
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count184
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
)
Runaway argument?
{blue 
! Paragraph ended before \TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.34 
     
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Too many }'s.
l.36         with a linebreak}
                              . %%%% Second and last thing Anna added
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/compile/output.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-06-29 L3 backend support: PDF mode
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1571 strings out of 480906
 21619 string characters out of 5908280
 262885 words of memory out of 5000000
 17227 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 535088 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,5n,37p,226b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 14135 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: `\newcommand*` should be `\newcommand`

Comment: `\def` should be `\long\def`.

Comment: I am late to the party, but maybe this comment is still useful for other readers: Under normal circumstances, when reading/tokenizing the .tex-input-file,  TeX takes a sequence of empty lines for a token `\par` while the star (`*`) with `\newcommand*` "tells" TeX not to accept the token `\par` with the arguments of the macro to define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
\newcommand*{\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack}[1]{%
  ...
}
```

you are telling LaTeX that the argument to `\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack` *cannot* contain blank lines (or `\par`).

Use

```
\newcommand{\TypsetInBlueOnlyIfCurrentColorIsBlack}[1]{%
  ...
}
```

Comment: That was so simple. Thank you!